# Invalid Simulink object name

Tags: matlab, моделирование

Добрый день.
В процессе моделирования системы возникла потребность в получении порядка знаменателя и порядка числителя управляемого объекта.
Пытаюсь получить следующим образом:

```
n=length(str2num(get_param('Adaptive_Controller/Object','Denominator')))-1
m=length(str2num(get_param('Adaptive_Controller/Object','Numerator')))-1
```

В следствие чего мне выдается ошибка: Invalid Simulink object name: Adaptive_Controller/Object ,хотя данный объект абсолютно точно существует. Прежде чем задать вопрос здесь, я погуглил и проблема могла бы быть в том, что я использую некорректное название или сам блок по какой-то случайности не подключен к цепи. Но ни первого ни второго у меня не наблюдается. ( пробовал получить параметры других блоков, всё получалось)
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема. 
Вот скриншот модели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]